# WCF service design - new method or a filter

Tags: c#, wcf, soa

I have a WCF service that returns phone numbers given an identifier. `[GetPhoneNumbersByIdentifier]`

I have another set of tables that stores the history of all phone number changes.

There is a requirement to bring back historical phone numbers when a consumer requests for it.

So shall I add a switch in my `GetPhoneNumbersByIdentifier [Bool GetHistory => True/False]`

Or should I create a new method - `GetAllPhoneNumbersByIdentifier`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two distinct methods and here is why:

- Should always make your code small and distinct pieces of functionality.
- I think combining the two could make the code dirty and less manageable in the future.
- Makes it easier to write test facets.